# Finding the solution of a PDE in a specific domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[image]

My thought: I tried to use polar coordinate to substitute $x,y$ with $r,\theta$ and got $u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta \theta}=1$

Since solution $u$ depends only on the distance to the origin,

the ODE reduced to:  $u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r=1$

Let $u_r=p$, then the ODE becomes: $pp'+\frac{1}{r}p=1$, but I do not know how to solve this ODE, although it has been reduced first-order.

Also, I am not sure whether I am on the right track. Is there an easy way to solve this problem？ Any help to this problem will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your ODE should be $p' + \frac 1r p = 1$, which can be solved by integration factor

Comment: Indeed it reduces to $(rp)'=r$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Use chain rule, Urr=(dp/dr)=(dp/du)*(du/dr)

Comment: There is no composition of functions here. There are just $u(r), u'(r)$ and $u''(r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ODE can be reduced to $p'(r)+\frac{p(r)}{r}=1$, where $p(r)=u'(r)$. Notice that, as mentioned in the comment section, there is no composition of functions here, this is but a 'change of variables' (or a relabel, if you prefer). Thus there is no need to use chain rule and the original ODE is not the correct one.

Using your notation, write $p=u_r$. Then, considering the integrating factor
$$
T(r)=e^{\int \frac1r \,dr}=r
$$
we multiply it by the equation to get
$$
ry'+y=r\Leftrightarrow(pr)'=r.
$$
Integrating leads to
$$
pr=\frac{r^2}{2}+c
$$
for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence,
$$
y=\frac{r}{2}+\frac{c}{r}.
$$
Finally, we get
$$
u=\int u_r\,dr=\int p\,dr=\frac{r^2}{4}+c_1\log(r)+c_2
$$
for some $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$, which are obtained using the boundary conditions $u(a)=u(b)=0$.